# передача файла в запросе к ClickHouse

Tags: node.js, clickhouse

Для работы с ClickHouse использую Nodejs.
Столкнулся с проблемой, что когда нужно выполнить запрос с большим списком в IN(), то это приводит к ошибке лимита символов в запросе.

Решается это через установку clickhouse-client и выполнение запроса из шелла, с подключением этого файла через флаг --external.

Вопрос. Можно ли повторить это, но из nodejs и без использования clickhouse-client?

UPD:

Использую библиотеку [@apla/clickhouse](https://github.com/apla/node-clickhouse)

Запросы делаю через стрим
и обработку событий

`let stream = ch.query(query);
 stream.on('data', (row) => {});
 stream.on('end',() => {});`

И тут всё ок.

Но чтоб передать в запрос фаил, использую вызов баша из ноды. А там уже вызываю утилиту clickhouse-client:

`let command = 'clickhouse-client --host=chHost --query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE user IN _data INTO OUTFILE outFile.csv FORMAT CSV" --external --file=fileName.csv --types=String;`

`cmd.get(command,(err, data, stderr) => {})`

в результате этого, я выгружаю данные в фаил на диске, и уже обрабатываю его нодой.

Как то это не правильно, но пока что это единственный рабочий вариант.

Есть ли возможность сделать тоже самое, то через обычный запрос из ноды, например как сделано выше, через стрим? Может какая библиотека. Искал, но так и не нашёл.

Comment: Дайте больше подробностей: какой библиотекой пользуетесь, как её инициализируете, как выполняете вызов...

Comment: обновил описание проблемы

Answer (score 2):

CH поддерживает конструкцию запроса `INSERT INTO x SELECT a, b, c FROM y` (вставка данных из результата подзапроса) 
Эта возможность так же поддерживается пакетом `@apla/clickhouse`

https://github.com/apla/node-clickhouse/blob/9c0f14e/test/05-insert.js#L185
https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/ru/query_language/insert_into/